# Querying data groups with total row before starting next group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to query some data in the below format in SQL Server:

- Id   Group   Price
- 1    A   10
- 2    A   20
- **Sum    30**
- 1    B   6
- 2    B   4
- **Sum    10**
- 1    C   100
- 2    C   200
- **Sum    300**

I was thinking to do it in the follwoing steps:

1. Query one group
2. In other query do sum
3. Use Union operator to combine this result set
4. Do step 1-3 for all groups and finally return all sub sets of data using union.

Is there a better way to do this ? May be using some out of box feature ? Please advise.

**Edit:**

As per suggestions and code sample I tried this code:

```
Select 
Case 
when id is null then 'SUM' 
else CAST(id as Varchar(10)) end as ID,

Case when [group] is null then 'ALL' else CAST([group] as Varchar(50)) end as [group]
,Price from
(
SELECT Id,  [Group],BGAApplicationID,Section, SUM(PrimaryTotalArea) AS price   
FROM vwFacilityDetails
where bgaapplicationid=1102
GROUP BY Id,  [Group],BGAApplicationID,Section  WITH ROLLUP
) a
```

And Even this code as well:

```
Select Id,  [Group],BGAApplicationID,Section, SUM(PrimaryTotalArea) AS price           
From   vwFacilityDetails
Where  Not ([group] Is Null And id Is Null And BGAApplicationId is null and section is null) and BGAApplicationId=1102
Group By Id,  [Group],BGAApplicationID,Section 
    With Rollup
```

In results it groups up the data but for every record it shows it 3 times (in both above codes) like:

- 2879 Existing Facilities Whole School    25.00
- 2879 Existing Facilities Whole School    25.00
- 2879 Existing Facilities    Whole School 25.00
- 2879 ALL 25.00

I guess there is some issue in my query, please guide me here as well.
Thanks

Comment: the ROLLUP keyword is the one to lookup

Comment: Do you need BGAApplicationID,Section in Selection and Grouping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server introduced [GROUPING SETS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which is what you should be looking to use.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57011/5)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
Create Table vwFacilityDetails (
  id int not null,
  [group] char(1) not null,
  PrimaryTotalArea int not null,
  Section int,
  bgaapplicationid int
);

Insert Into vwFacilityDetails (id, [group], Section,bgaapplicationid,PrimaryTotalArea) values
  (1, 'A', 1,1102,2),
  (1, 'A', 1,1102,1),
  (1, 'A', 1,1102,7),
  (2, 'A', 1,1102,20),
  (1, 'B', 1,1102,6),
  (2, 'B', 1,1102,4),
  (1, 'C', 1,1102,100),
  (2, 'C', 1,1102,200);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Id is null then 'SUM'
            ELSE Right(Id,10) end Id,
       [Group],BGAApplicationID,Section,
       SUM(PrimaryTotalArea) price   
FROM vwFacilityDetails
where bgaapplicationid=1102
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (Id,[Group],BGAApplicationID,Section),
  ([Group])
)
ORDER BY [GROUP],
         ID;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57011/5/0)**:

```
|  ID | GROUP | BGAAPPLICATIONID | SECTION | PRICE |
----------------------------------------------------
|   1 |     A |             1102 |       1 |    10 |
|   2 |     A |             1102 |       1 |    20 |
| SUM |     A |           (null) |  (null) |    30 |
|   1 |     B |             1102 |       1 |     6 |
|   2 |     B |             1102 |       1 |     4 |
| SUM |     B |           (null) |  (null) |    10 |
|   1 |     C |             1102 |       1 |   100 |
|   2 |     C |             1102 |       1 |   200 |
| SUM |     C |           (null) |  (null) |   300 |
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select
  id,
  [Group],
  SUM(price) AS price
From
  Test
Group By
  [group],
  id 
With
  Rollup
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/080cd/8

Comment: I have tried your suggested code but looks I am missing something. Can you please see my edit and guide. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Case when id is null then 'SUM' else CAST(id as Varchar(10)) end as ID
,Case when [group] is null then 'ALL' else CAST([group] as Varchar(10)) end as [group]
,Price from
(
SELECT id, [group], SUM(price) AS Price
FROM IG
GROUP BY [GROUP],ID WITH ROLLUP
) a
```

Comment: I have tried this. Can you please see my edit and advise. Thanks